# File corrupted after creating the second document based on template with macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have many Excel templates containing VBA code. Some of them create new documents based on other templates with VBA code. They all worked well until last Friday, but today I got a bad surprise: creating the first document based on a template with macro works well, but creating the second gets corrupted code.

I was able to reproduce the problem with two very small templates created from scratch:

1. double click on the first file to create the first document
2. double click on the second one to create another document

At this point you can see on the VBA editor that the VBA project for the second document is corrupted. Signs of corruption are wrong icons on the Wrokbook and Worksheet modules on the project explorer and message about catastrophic failure if you try to compile.

Using first the second template, then the first one will corrupt the second one that is opened.

Click [here](https://universecorp-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/stefanomenci_universecorp_onmicrosoft_com/EtZ0ij2I_65EiR8bBZxIhZ4BlNRbR-DKY1GC7Wm-JY0NoQ?e=DWGnzW) to get the files to reproduce the problem.

**EDIT**

If you don't want to download the files (I understand, thanks to the comment @Mathieu Guindon) you can create them by simply:

1. create a new Excel file
2. add a module with a simple sub that shows a message box
3. save it as a template with macro
4. repeat with a second file

Now you have the two files that you can use to reproduce the problem described above.

Comment: I don't think I'm the only one that's reluctant to download some random file that corrupts Office documents... the question should be self-contained (see [mcve]), with screenshots and code snippets as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has confirmed that the build 1905 is broken and corrupts the second Excel document created from a template with macros.

They sent me a (long) list of steps to uninstall Office 365, run a script to clear some cache, create a new configuration and reinstall specifying the semi-annual channel for the updates and prevent the 1905 from being installed.

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2019 MSO (16.0.11629.20210) 32-bit.

===  Tested: Opening sequence and filetypes  ===

• FAIL - Open an Excel template that contains VBA, then another one that contains VBA.

• OK - Open an Excel template that contains VBA, then Excel template with no code in any module.

• OK - Open an Excel template that contains VBA, then an XLSB (Excel binary file) that was created by resaving any of the previous code-containing workbooks.

===  Tested: VBA Editor's Immediate window  ===

• FAIL - In VBA Editor, open a code module from the second or any subsequent workbook that has VBA in it, then run a command in the Immediate window.

• OK - In VBA Editor, open a code module from the first workbook, then run a command in the Immediate window.

===  Couldn't find any MS article about it.  ===

Not listed on https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fixes-or-workarounds-for-recent-issues-in-excel-for-windows-49d932ce-0240-49cf-94df-1587d9d97093 but it's definitely an Excel issue:

Can't open more than one macro-enabled workbook and have macros actually run, unless the 2nd and all subsequent macro workbooks are .XLSB.

Even with no addins loaded.

Symptoms:

• Excel is configured to allow macros, but no macros run.

• Excel is configured to prompt for macros, but doesn't.

• Attempting to run a macro in workbooks after the initial workbook causes Catastrophic Error, Automation Error, or Compile Error.